# Use default value if scan is escaped

Tags: r, function, controls

I need to write a function that will ask user for a value and if scan is esaped with pushing Esc on a keyboard, set up to some default value. But the following doesn't work:

```
set_value <- function() {
  default_value <- 0
  value <- ''
  value <- scan(what = integer(), nmax = 1, quiet = TRUE)
  if (value == '') return(default_value) else return(value)
}
```

How can I achieve this? I need to stop a script when asking for input, so I shouldn't probably use a `readline` but stick to `scan`

### Edit

As many of you posted an answer and all of those result in a strange behaviour I decided to elaborate on what happens here. Any of those answers don't setup to default value when I push Esc on a keyboard. Please see the output from my console with @RuiBarradas's function.

```
> set_value <- function() {
+   default_value <- 0
+   value <- NULL
+   on.exit(if(is.null(value)) return(default_value) else return(value))
+   value <- scan(what = integer(), nmax = 1, quiet = TRUE)
+ }
> res
Error: object 'res' not found
> res <- set_value()
1:  # Here I pushed Esc on a keyboard

> res
[1] 9
```

`9` is a value that was provided to scan in previous `scan` call, but wasn't assigned to `res` at any point (as you can observe `res` was empty before calling `set_value`).

### Edit 2

It seems that R session somehow keeps remembering the values previously inputted in scan, no matter to which variable a scan input was assigned. So when I call a function and assign it to variable `x`, then call a function while assigning it to `y`, but escape from `scan` it still assigned PREVIOUSLY scanned value (see below).

```
> set_value <- function() {
+     default_value <- 0
+     r <- default_value
+     tryCatch(r<-scan(what = integer(), nmax = 1, quiet = TRUE),  finally = return(r))
+ }
> 
> x <- set_value()
1: 2
> x
[1] 2
> y
Error: object 'y' not found
> y <- set_value()
1: 

> y 
[1] 2
```

Can anybody explain this behaviour?

Comment: tried it, but when `scan` is escaped return is not even hit and the function seems to return previously inputted value (from previous function call)

Comment: Well, then default value is returned always (even when some value is inputted in scan)

Comment: I cannot reproduce the behaviour in the edit. With me all works as expected. Do you have a file named `.RData` in the working directory of R? (That's the file anme not an extension.) Maybe you are restoring a previous session or something weird like that. Try to quit, delete said file if it exists  and restart R.

Comment: @RuiBarradas I have deleted .RData file and the value was setup to 0 only in a first escaped call of `set_value`. Once I set a value to 2 and try to call the function once again, escape it then the value is not restarted to 0 anymore, but keeps being 2. So it seems the function works ok only on a very first call.

Comment: I have made another edit with an example.

Comment: But that's not the function I have posted. In my function `value` is set to `NULL` and `default_value <- 0`. Then, what returns the function's value is the `on.exit` instruction. I thought about `tryCatch` but since like I have written it it works, I would prefer to have `tryCatch` *outside* the function. (To catch character inputs, for instance.)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
set_value <- function() {
  default_value <- 0
  value <- ''
  value <- scan(what = integer(), nmax = 1, quiet = TRUE)
  if (length(value) == 0) return(default_value) else return(value)
}
```

Comment: Doesn't assign the default value when `scan` is escaped.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
 set_value <- function() {
 default_value <- 0
 # value <- ''
 value <- scan(what = integer(), nmax = 1, quiet = TRUE)
 if (length(value) == 0) return(default_value) else return(value)
 }
```

Comment: Doesn't assign the default value when `scan` is escaped.

Answer (score 0):

The following does set the default value when `scan` is escaped.

```
set_value <- function() {
  default_value <- 0
  value <- NULL
  on.exit(if(is.null(value)) return(default_value) else return(value))
  value <- scan(what = integer(), nmax = 1, quiet = TRUE)
}

rm(res)    # Make sure 'res' does not exist
res <- set_value()
res
#[1] 0
```

**Edit.**

Here is a more complete session.

```
> rm(res)
> res <- set_value()    # Press <ESC>
1: 

> res
[1] 0
> rm(res)
> res <- set_value()    # Press <Enter>
1: 
> res
integer(0)
> rm(res)
> res <- set_value()    # Press 123
1: 123
> res
[1] 123
```

Comment: That is weeeird, but it doesn't work for me. Still, in case of escape this set up to previously scaned value.

Comment: Please see a copy of my console: `> set_value <- function() {
+     default_value <- 0
+     value <- NULL
+     on.exit(if(is.null(value)) return(default_value) else return(value))
+     value <- scan(what = integer(), nmax = 1, quiet = TRUE)
+ }
> res <- set_value()
1: 

> res
[1] 30` where 30 is a last value inputted to scan function... It wasn't even stored in `res` because I just created this variable

Comment: `r <-  scan(what = integer(), nmax = 1);print(1)`  doesn't print 1 when scan is escaped (even executed from a function). It looks like escaping was causing some fault; Knowing what fault could help to catch it. Any idea?

Comment: @jakes I'm  running R 3.5.1 on ubuntu 18.04 but I don't believe this makes a difference. If you escape `scan` the previous value of `res` will still be the one, there's no error in what you are saying, it's expected behaviour.

Comment: Please see an edit of my post, there's an explanation what happens here.

Answer (score 0):

This code seems OK :

```
set_value <- function() {
 default_value <- 0
 r <- default_value
 tryCatch(r<-scan(what = integer(), nmax = 1, quiet = TRUE),  finally = return(r))
}

rm("x")
x <- set_value()

1: # escape pressed there
x
# [1] 0

x <- 9
x <- set_value()

1: #escape pressed there
x
# [1] 0
```

But the case of the enter key is not handled. To do so, the return instruction must be changed to :

```
return(ifelse(length(r)==0),default_value,r))
```

Comment: Please see an edit of my post, there's an explanation what happens here.

Comment: I have tried your function and the issue is still present. Please see edit 2 with an output from my console.

Comment: @jakes I've got it! All my experiments were done under the standard RGui et there it works perfectly as for the solution of Ruy. But if you execute the code from RStudio (I used both 1.1.453 and 1.0.453), then the code behaves as you describe. It is not a problem with R but with the GUI you use.

Comment: @jakes Without the quiet=TRUE, my code runs too with Rstudio. The problems seems being that quiet=TRUE bypass the `catch`and its finally and what you get in the variable x is not the result of the last scan but the variable x unchanged.